# Running "python3 setup.py bdist_wheel" on a /mnt/c/... path results in a "Errno 13 Permission Denied" error

Tags: software-installation, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to build a bdist package of my python app but the command `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` fails with error `Errno 13: Permission Denied` when is launched from a subfolder of `/mnt/c/`.
The same command (with the same set of sources) launched from a subfolder of `/home/<username>` succeeds.
This happens only for the `bdist_wheel` parameter; with the `sdist` parameter all goes fine.
Any idea?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: Running into the same issue - anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

I had it pass by specifying a temporary directory that is not under /mnt/c.

One can use the following:

```
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --bdist-dir ~/temp/bdistwheel
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify this option when calling pip?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the answer was already out there: https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/258#issuecomment-514934944

The issue is resolved by granting "Full control" to "Authenticated Users" in the Windows File settings for the folder that one is trying to work on through WSL.

[image]